# how to print images in ngx-gallery?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gallery

I'm using angular and ngx-gallery to view the images. how can i print the images in the gallery?
here is my ngx-gallery code in html:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="mt-1">
   <ngx-gallery #gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="images" *ngIf="images.length"></ngx-gallery>
</div>
```

and my gallery code in component:

```
this.galleryOptions = [
            {
              width: '600px',
              height: '1100px',
              thumbnailsColumns: 4,
              imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
            },
            // max-width 800
            {
              breakpoint: 400,
              // width: '2%',
              // height: '2px',
              imagePercent: 99,
              thumbnailsPercent: 1,
              thumbnailsMargin: 20,
              thumbnailMargin: 20,
            },
            // max-width 400
            {
              breakpoint: 400,
              preview: false,
            }
          ];

          if (mail.mail.rows[0].attach_files) {
            for (let i in mail.mail.rows[0].attach_files) {
              let image = JSON.parse(mail.mail.rows[0].attach_files[i]);
              this.galleryImages = [
                {
                  small: '/assets/uploads/mail_files/' + image.name,
                  medium: '/assets/uploads/mail_files/' + image.name,
                  big: '/assets/uploads/mail_files/' + image.name
                }
              ];
              this.images.push(this.galleryImages[0]);
            }
          }
```

I have a button on my page and I want to open a popup window to print them.